# Tag merge request: 'tax' and 'taxes'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Can we merge the [tax](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tax) tag into [taxes](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes we can](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes).